# What does this PowerShell syntax mean?

Tags: powershell

In powershell what does the syntax $x = . { ... } mean? How is it different from $x = @( ... )
From what I can tell they both create an array of the provided values but their output is slightly different.

I came across it in this script https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher when the author defines the handlers in the async example. Is there any significance to doing it that way? Other async examples for filewatcher use similar code.

```
$x = @(1,2,3)
$y = . {1,2,3}
@($x,$y) | foreach-object {
    $_
    $_.GetType()
}

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
1,2,3
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
1
2
3
```

Non Trivial Example

```
$handlers = . {
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed  -Action $Action 
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created  -Action $Action
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Deleted  -Action $Action
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Renamed  -Action $Action
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In PowerShell what does the syntax `$x = . { ... }` mean?

- `{ ... }` is a [Script Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2) which is used to store an expression.
- `.` is the [dot sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-), which can be used to execute a *script block*.

When put together, `. { ... }`, the script block is executed as soon as it's interpreted by PowerShell.

> How is it different from `$x = @( ... )`?

- `@( ... )` is the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--), one of the ways you have to define a [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-6.0) in PowerShell.

For this particular case, I don't see a difference between both because your script block is storing a `System.Array` and the dot sourcing operator doesn't change the return type of your expression.

However, when wrapping a *sub-expression* in `@( .. )` you can ensure that the return will always be an *array* even if the sub-expression returns `$null`:

```sh
@( $null ).GetType()    # is an array
(. { $null }).GetType() # is an error
```

If you were to use the [`.Invoke()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-scriptblock-invoke(system-object())) to execute the script block, the difference would've been the return type, from `System.Array` to `` Collection`1 ``:

```sh
({1, 2, 3}.Invoke()).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name              BaseType
-------- -------- ----              --------
True     True     Collection`1      System.Object
```

---

As for the linked code, the author is wrapping multiple calls to `Register-ObjectEvent` inside the script block and executing it, there is no difference either because there are multiple calls to the cmdlet and the return type of both expressions is an array. If however, we do the same with only one call to the cmdlet with the script block example we get the [output type from `Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7.2#outputs):

```sh
$watcher1 = [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher]::new($pwd.Path)
$watcher2 = [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher]::new($pwd.Path)

$handler1 = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher1 -EventName Changed -Action { Write-Host 'hello '}
}
$handler2 = @(
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher2 -EventName Changed -Action { Write-Host 'hello '}
)
$handler1.GetType() # => PSEventJob
$handler2.GetType() # => object[]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Could you explain a little more what the dot-sourcing portion is doing? If it's mostly irrelevant in the trivial example, what about in the added edit?

Comment: @Dylan hope the update clarifies that for you